# react redux server pagination and sorting

Tags: reactjs, redux, datatable, material-ui

I have a data table which supports server side pagination and sorting.
I am using Redux as my store and React for display. The scenario is :

I have 5000 rows and hence server side pagination. Now the real challange is :

**How do I use redux optimally to fetch data remotely in combination with Pagination and Sorting ?**.

[This link](http://Server%20Pagination%20-%20How%20to%20handle%20Previous%20Page%20and%20Next%20Page%20in%20REDUX%20%20https://medium.com/spotlight-on-javascript/working-with-paginated-api-in-redux-be871818e444) explains how I can handle server pagination by not hitting the server API for repeated data. But how can I handle pagination and sorting (together) in terms of saving data in REDUX and not making unnecessary calls to API for repeated data.

Example :
Pagination - Page Size = 10 =>
I am on Page1 -> I get first 10 records and display / save them with a FLAG that Page 1 data fetched true (as mentioned in the above article). Same for other pages. Now when I go to ANY page number; I check the flag, based on which I fetch data from REDUX or API.

If sorting is introduced in this solution; what can be done ? Need optimal solutions performance wise. Thanks !

Comment: For sorting you should scrap your current data in Redux and do another request, start over. You can't properly ensure you'd have all relevant data on the front end when you sort unless you had ALL the data on the front.

Comment: I am not sure but why you want to save whole data in redux. If user go each page it will save whole save data. How it is relevant in your case?

Comment: I want to give faster page access and load experience and do not want to go to the server for same API call. But what is the best industry practices / guidelines when it comes to handling such lists (which keep growing) - Pull fresh every time from API ? Would it be performant ?